# how can I copy specific line of list and paste on specific line of another list in python?

Tags: python, list, line, extend

I have a list which I want to add seven line of it to one line In another list (not with append), I do this works but I get error

```
trainer = [] 
for j in range (0, 22): 
  for i in range(len(train)): 
    if i//7==j: 
      trainer[j].extend(train[i])
```

Comment: Posting a link to a picture isn't going to cut it. No one is going to take the time to type your code into their editor. The picture of your code doesn't even show the whole story. Show us your code, that is, your attempt to make your code do what you want it to do. If we can't see it, we can't help. And please take the time to read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend only a list(or sequence) with another list(or sequence).
Thats why you need to create a list in trainer[j].
train[i] must be a list as well.

```
train = range(1000) #example of train data
trainer = []
for j in range (0, 22):
    trainer.append([]) #initialize trainer[j] with an empty list
    for i in range(len(train)):
        if i//7==j:
            trainer[j].extend([train[i]]) #extend with another list
```

Comment: Yes you are right!, thank you. I defined train list in my code but I forget to write it there, but my problem solved by these bracket: trainer[j].extend([train[i]])

Comment: And I have another question if you can help me :)
I want to make numpy array and make copy of trainer list in it, line by line but without "\n" because I want to use its parameter for math function, how can I do this?

Comment: try this: trainer_numpy = [np.array([train_element for train_element in train if train_element != "\n"]) for train in trainer]

Comment: you need to import numpy: import numpy as np